# How do I insert values from a form using php and sql using my own script?

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli

Hi first time user and beginner when it comes to using php,

How do I go about inserting values from a form using php and sql.

Ive created the following code using php and sql.
here is my form.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "datab";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// prepare and bind with form attached.
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $firstname, $lastname, $email);
?>
<form action="/t.php" method="post">
  First name:
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
   <br> Last Name:
   <input type="text" name="lastname">
    <br>Email:
   <input type="text" name="email">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
// set parameters and execute
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$stmt->execute();


$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

the t.php file is simply saying entries were added successfully even though there is no logic there, just a simple echo comment.

I just want to know how to insert data using forms with php and sql.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "datab";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
?>   

<form action="/t.php" method="post">
      First name:
      <input type="text" name="firstname">
       <br> Last Name:
       <input type="text" name="lastname">
        <br>Email:
       <input type="text" name="email">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>



    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])) {
    // set parameters and execute
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    // prepare and bind with form attached.
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $firstname, $lastname, $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

To prevent duplication, save the db connection in a file called `db.php`.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "datab";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Then, include it in the `main.php` file. Here's the `main.php` file written with [prepared statement errors prevented](https://developer.hyvor.com/php/prepared-statements).

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {    
    try {
        # check if all the params are set
        if (
            !empty($_POST['firstname']) && 
            !empty($_POST['lastname']) &&
            !empty($_POST['email'])
        ) {
            $firstname = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['firstname']));
            $lastname = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['lastname']));
            $email = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['email']));

            include_once 'db.php';

            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

            if (
                $stmt &&
                $stmt->bind_param("sss", $firstname, $lastname, $email) &&
                $stmt -> execute() 
            ) {
                echo "Yay! Inserted.";
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Error in MYSQLI Statement");   
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Some data is not set");
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {   
        die($e -> getMessage());
    }
} else { ?>

<form action="" method="post">
  First name:
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
   <br> Last Name:
   <input type="text" name="lastname">
    <br>Email:
   <input type="text" name="email">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

The strings should be [validated](https://developer.hyvor.com/tutorials/php/forms-validation) before inserted into the database. Here I have used `htmlspecialchars()` to prevent XSS and `trim()` to remove unnecessary white spaces.

Thanks.

Comment: I have schanged the code, check it now. I changed `form action=""` to submit to the same page. and a PHP syntax error is fixed.

Comment: You can include it from another file if you need. When submitting to the same file, you can create [sticky forms](https://developer.hyvor.com/tutorials/php/forms-sticky) easily.

Answer (score 0):

Form action will call t.php, but you dont have it!
Create two files: myHtml.html and t.php in the same folder

myHtml.html

```
<html>
    <form action="t.php" method="post">
        First name:
        <input type="text" name="firstname">
        <br> Last Name:
        <input type="text" name="lastname">
        <br>Email:
        <input type="text" name="email">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</html>
```

t.php

```
<?php
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "datab";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// prepare and bind with form attached.
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $firstname, $lastname, $email);

// set parameters and execute
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```